# Android: Changing visibility of components in fragment at runtime

Tags: android-fragments

In Android app, I am using a menubar with tabs attached to it. And each tab has a fragment.
I am trying to set visibility of components (like button) in a fragment to invisible at runtime. But it is not taking effect.

What am I missing?

Main activity class calls a method in Fragment class to set visibility of the button.
But it is not taking effect.

In fragment class,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fm_hd_fragment, container, false);
        multicastUp = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.FmHdMulticastUp);
        multicastDown = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.FmHdMulticastDown);
        multicastDisplay = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.FmHdCurrentMulticast);
        .
        .
        .
}

public static void showcontrol(){
        multicastDisplay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        multicastDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        multicastUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

In class that wants to update this fragment

```
 FragmentWrapper.showcontrol();
```

Comment: edited the question with what I have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue...

I was trying to update activity from Service directly.
When I use intents from service to update Activity, the UI update works fine.